# Change default from Extern to Static

Tags: c, gcc, static, c99

I always forget to add the 'static' prefix to my variabeles and functions, and so the GCC marks them as extern. Is it possible to change this behaviour so that it marks everything static by default. And is there a performance difference between the two types at runtime, or is it more a formality?

Comment: You might want to dump symbols from the compiled code to see if there's anything you've forgotten to make static. Try `nm`, `objdump` and other tools like these.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is it possible to change this behaviour so that it marks everything static by default.

Not to my knowledge.

> And is there a performance difference between the two types at runtime, or is it more a formality?

Yes, `gcc` is able to perform further optimizations when objects or functions are `static` specified. For example, `gcc`(even in `-O0`) will inline a `static` specified function that is called only once.

Comment: Do you know if GCC will detect that the variabele isnt used in other files, and threats it as static at compile-time? Or do I always need to explicitly add it?

Comment: @Joshua It will not. Or at least not by default. Newer `gcc` versions have link time optimizations: see `gcc` options `-flto` and `-fwhole-program`.

Answer (score 1):

First of all: The `extern` modifier is **not** default. That qualifier indicates that the item mentioned will be defined in another compilation unit, so it's only appropriate for declaring things like global variables.

There is no way to make the `static` modifier default, because there is no `dynamic` modifier which would cancel out this default. As such, there'd be no way to write working code with that default in place: every function and variable would be `static`, which would cause the compiler to generate an empty output file!

> Is there a performance difference between the two types at runtime, or is it more a formality?

The compiler can perform some optimizations on `static` functions and variables which cannot be performed on dynamic ones. In particular, `static` functions and variables which are never referenced may be dropped entirely, and `static` functions can be inlined more aggressively.

Comment: If extern is not the default, what is the default then?

Comment: The default is nothing (i.e, no modifier). Static variables do not have linkage -- they cannot be referenced from other files.

Comment: So what is the difference between 'nothing' and extern then? Because it sounds like they offer the same. It seems weird that there is no option to use static by default, because the times that I need global variabeles to be accessible from other files are much more rare compared to the times I need them to be static. Hopefully GCC is smart enough to notice at compile-time that the variabele isnt used anywhere else, and compiles it as static.

Comment: Just remember to type static in front of things! ;)

Comment: Difference: `extern` generates linkage only, not storage. GCC cannot detect that a variable isn't referenced externally, because it only looks at one C file at a time. By the time linking happens, it's too late to static-ify anything.